# "Inquiry" vs. "investigation"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

When I'm involved in a project with the goal of analyzing (following some previously stated criteria) a set of research papers, which word is more suitable: *inquiry* or *investigation*? Or neither? If neither, please let me know what your suggestion is.

Comment: Investigation or analysis.

Comment: Look up _investigate_, _inquire_, _investigation_, and _inquiry_ in any dictionary.  I think _investigation_ is a bit more suitable, but that wouldn't preclude _inquiry_ from being used; there is some overlap of meaning.

Comment: Why do you use interrobang rather than question mark?

Comment: @AngloSaxon I've modified the question.. thanks for the tip.

Comment: @J.R. that's the point. It's, like, very confusing to decide which word is more suitable, especially in case that I need to write down what I'm really doing, as a task in a research paper, for instance. I should use the most appropriate term.

Comment: @IvanMachado: Fair enough.  Chances are, though, if it's that confusing, even after examining all the definitions, then the differences are so inconsequential that you needn't worry about picking the "wrong" word; either will do just fine.

Comment: @J.R. you're sure! I'll follow your advice! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you assessing these papers for the purpose of assigning a "grade"?  In that case, you are involved in analyzing their inquiries for the purpose of assessment.  If you are analyzing these research papers, then you are figuring out distinctive features of each such as validity, reliability, and writing or argument strength.
If you are "investigating" these research papers, it sounds more like checking into the originality of each to me.

Comment: Yep, I'm intended to deeply analyze a set of studies and grade them, according to a predefined "quality analysis score".